# Which Development Method Should I use for creating a relatively small game project

Tags: vb6, methods

Hey people, second question. So I'm working on an idea/design document for a virtual tabletop RPG system. It will include menus, sound, some artwork(graphics), be able to add content without redoing code, and have networking capabilities(for multiplayer, as in, a dungeon master acting as a server).

This isn't a huge project, and I plan on using visual basic 6, as that's what I get to use at school, I plan on redoing it in another language that I can port to iphone and android later on, but vb6 for now.

But the question is, what method should I use: Agile, Prototyping, Structured, RAD etc.

I only know a basic idea of what each is, and it seems that structured is not a very good choice, but out of the other choices, which would be best for a fairly small game project?

Comment: Why in the world would you use an obsolete development environment like VB6?

Comment: @John: More VB6 bashing? You can constructively offer alternatives instead and leave the OP judge for himself, ok?

Comment: @wqw: calling VB6 obsolete is not "bashing", just the plain fact. The alternatives are "almost anything else that isn't obsolete".

Comment: @wqw: here's a good definition of "obsolete": VB6 is unsupported! See http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/?p1=2971

Comment: What about the "in the world" part of your comment! You understand perfectly what I'm talking about, stop acting... The OP might have million reasons to choose a legacy technology that you couldn't know about.

Comment: bit delayed, my account glitched, and I couldn't post a comment until i had higher rep. So I'm using VB6 because that's what my school teaches with(I will be pushing for a change in language(probably to vb.net)).

Answer (score 0):

Agile == Prototyping == RAD.  They're all the same thing.

I have no idea what "Structured" means.  If you mean "Structured Programming", you need to move out of the '80's and switch to Object-Oriented.

Between that and the VB6 technology, it appears that your question has been obsoleted by the advance of the state of the art.

Comment: structured programming approach, I'm not sure if people still recognise this, but it's when you go through the defining the problem, planning the solution, implementing the solution stages in the specific rigid order.

Comment: Structured Programming never meant "waterfall methodology".  It meant no goto statements and the more structured use of loop and if-statements.  If by "structured programming" you mean a waterfall-style methodology, please update the question to use the words "waterfall methodology.  You're using the term Structured Programming incorrectly.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_programming

Comment: oh gawd, I hate my school. I wish they would get the terms right... I have a new question that I will post up very shortly, and is also more important.

Comment: @Blue: If by "structured", you mean a "structured methodology", then you **must** say that.  Of course, the opposite of "structured" is "unstructured", i.e., no methodology.  So "structured methodology" covers all methodologies including "Agile" and "Waterfall"; not a very useful term.

Answer (score 0):

try to use vb.net.., it is just same as visula basic but more advance. the only thing that i dont like is it is si heavy for the memory. but more graphical than vb6.